# Launch Multiple copies of a program

Tags: python

I am using python 3.3
Lets say i have a program called
Program1.py which has something like

```
def write_file(filename):
    with open filename as f:
         f.write('sometext')
```

In another program say program2.py 
I would like to launch multiple copies of the program program1.py how would i do that but

Is there way to spawn two threads and execute the program1.py 10 times ?

Comment: Import program1  in program2 and then call the function.

Comment: The Actual Program is huge and over 100 lines of code not something i can import and call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the spawn*() functions.  E.g.:

```
import os
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "./program1.py", "hello")
```

Comment: Hi Apologies for not being clear on the question is there a way i can use Concurrent processing to spawn the program say i want to do this 10 times but using two processes

Comment: I don't know enough about concurrent processing to say.  I'd suggest doing your own research on this, and if you get stuck, post what you tried on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ because this is a design question IMHO.